# i am getting an error in my python code can you help me fix it?

Tags: python

I am getting the error:

```
    randint = randint(1, 2)
TypeError: 'int' object is not callable
```

This is my code. I have no idea what caused this to happen, is it something to do with going over the loop twice, because it allows me to answer the first question then fails: [screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPKSn.png).

```
from random import randint

score = 0

print('\n\n\n\nyour score right now is ', score, 'if it drops below zero you lose')

def make_question(num, italian, answer):

    global score

    if randint == int(num):
        a = input('\nWhat does ' + str(italian) + ' mean? ')
        if a == str(answer):
            score += 1
            print('\ncorrect your score is: ', score)
        else:
            score -= 1
            print('\nincorrect your score is now: ', score)


while True:
    randint = randint(1, 2)
    make_question(1, 'ripetere', 'repeat')
    make_question(2, 'puoi/potere ripetere', 'can you repeat that')
```

Answer (score 1):

The first time you do:

```
randint = randint(1, 2)
```

`randint` is the function from the `random` module, and the call works. Then you replace it with either `1` or `2`, and now it's just an `int`. Use a different name for the value you're generating (say, `whichquestion = randint(1, 2)` and replace `if randint == int(num):` with `if whichquestion == int(num):`), so you don't discard your handle to the function you need.